# Tipsy tooltip not affixing to D3 element

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tooltip, circle-pack, tipsy

I actually had this working a few days ago but something must have changed as now it's not working properly. The tooltip does display when you hover over the relevant element but always in the top left of the screen. I can see when using 'inspect element' in the browser window that the style of the tipsy tooltip is always set to `top: 0px; left: 0px` which suggests that it's not computing new values for the position.

This shows the creation of the elements I'm trying to attach a tooltip to (circles of varying size in a bubble chart) along with the initialization of tipsy:

```
function d3bubbles(dataset) {

    var diameter = 960;

    // create new pack layout set to variable 'bubble'
    var bubble = d3.layout.pack()
                          // no sorting, size allocated 960x960
                          .sort(null)
                          .size([diameter, diameter])

    var canvas = d3.select("#mainBlock").append("svg")
                               .attr("width", diameter)
                               .attr("height", diameter)
                               .append("g")

    d3.json("cleanJson.json", function (data) {

        // run pack layout specified above returning array of nodes
        // associated with 'data' from JSON file
        // outputs array with computed position of all nodes as 'nodes'
        // and populates some data for each node:
        // depth, starting at 0 for root, x coordinate of node,
        // y coordinate of node, radius r of node

        var nodes = bubble.nodes(data);

        var node = canvas.selectAll(".node")
                         .data(nodes)
                         .enter()
                         // standard html element to display svg
                         .append("g")
                         .attr("class", "node")
                         .attr("transform", function (d) {
                             return "translate(" + d.x + ", " + d.y + ")";
                         });

        node.append("circle")
            // radius from data
            .attr("r", function (d) {
                return d.r;
            })
            // set stroke for circles but only on leaf nodes
            .attr("stroke", function (d) {
                return d.children ? "": "#f4efdd";
            })
            .attr("stroke-width", 10);

        // tooltip
        $('svg circle').tipsy( { 
            gravity: 'w',
            fade: true,
            html: true, 
            title: function() {
                var d = this.__data__;
                return d.children ? "" : d.value + " Manuscripts"; 
            }
        })
    });
};
```

`#mainBlock` refers to the id of a `section` in my html. When I run this and hover over the circles of data in the bubble chart, the tooltips do appear, but all in the top left of the screen. Can anyone spot anything wrong here that would be causing this error?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately tipsy had been created much more before SVG graphics become available. If you have to use tipsy, you may need to some jQuery tweaks as like as follows:

```
  jQuery('svg g.node').mousemove(function( event ) {
       // 
       jQuery('.tipsy').css('left',(event.pageX+16)+'px');
       jQuery('.tipsy').css('top',(event.pageY-16)+'px');
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Your d3 version is too new for tipsy to support. For d3.js v6, check d3-v6-tip. https://www.npmjs.com/package/d3-v6-tip